# Cannot use class level attribute at instantiation, variable not defined yet

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a class where the attribute `d` has a default value of `None` and is derived from the class level attribute `DEFAULT_RATIO` if no positional argument is given at instantiation. Here is what I have so far:

```
class test_class:
    
    DEFAULT_RATIO = 0.5
    
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        if not d:
            self.d = DEFAULT_RATIO * self.a
        else:
            self.d = d
```

However I get this error if I test the instantiation with `b = test_class(3, 1, 1)`

```
NameError: name 'DEFAULT_RATIO' is not defined
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Use `self.DEFAULT_RATIO` or `self.__class__.DEFAULT_RATIO` (if you want to be more specific).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @schwobaseggl, to avoid hardcoding the class name in case you rename the class or subclass `test_class`, you need to prepend the class attribute `DEFAULT_RATIO` by `self.__class__`:

```
class test_class:
    
    DEFAULT_RATIO = 0.5
    
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        if not d:
            self.d = self.__class__.DEFAULT_RATIO * self.a  # <- HERE
        else:
            self.d = d
```

Comment: Hardcoding `test_class` into a method gives me an itch. You have an instance (`self`) available. Use it to find out whatever type it is at runtime or use it directly as it has access to its class's attributes!

Comment: As an explanation (other than renaming redundancies), one might subclass `test_class` for the sole purpose of changing the default ratio. In that case, one would have to rewrite the entire constructor in your first variant.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, You're totally right. I updated my answer according your good advice

Comment: Wouldn't just using `self.DEFAULT_RATIO` achieve the same result?

Comment: Yes, you will obtain the same result. Just a matter of taste :-) I prefer `self.__class__.DEFAULT_RATIO`

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
class test_class:
    DEFAULT_RATIO = 0.5

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d if d is not None else test_class.DEFAULT_RATIO * self.a
```

You could use `self.__class__` instead of class name itself if you don't want to hardcode the name.

The error you are getting is because the methods inside classes are not nested in class namespaces, instead they are nested in classes' **enclosing scope** (which is global namespace here). So you have to access the class variable through it's class name.

Answer (score -1):

You're telling the program to retrieve the variable called `DEFAULT_RATIO` *outside of* the class's scope. That line should be `self.d = test_class.DEFAULT_RATIO * self.a` instead.